# Where are React app folders and files created in VS Code located on my computer?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I was doing a React tutorial to create a simple restaurant app. At the beginning of one of the videos, the instructor announced that he had added an assets folder with images. But he never explained how he did it. That's when it occurred to me that I have no idea where the files I created exist outside of VS Code.

Once the React app is created/named and the basic folder structure is created, where do those folders and files live on my computer? I assume there must be a root folder with the app name and sub folder for modules, public, and src.

Comment: How did you create them? If you used `create-react-app`, where did you run that command? Have you tried the usual command to tell you what directory your shell is in? Tried to open one of the files in its directory (on macOS this is called "Reveal in Finder")?

Comment: try to `right click` on one of the files within VSCode and then click on `Open in file explorer`

Comment: select the file and use the shift+Alt+R key to Reveal in File Explorer